# How can I reference columns by their names in python calling SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some code which I've been using to query MySQL, and I'm hoping to use it with SQLite. My real hope is that this will not involve making too many changes to the code. Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work with SQLite:

```
cursor.execute(query)

rows = cursor.fetchall()

data = []
for row in rows
  data.append(row["column_name"])
```

This gives the following error:

```
 TypeError: tuple indices must be integers
```

Whereas if I change the reference to use a column number, it works fine:

```
  data.append(row[1])
```

Can I execute the query in such a way that I can reference columns by their names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but here's what I typically do to retrieve a record set using a DB-API 2 compliant module:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT foo, bar, baz, quux FROM table WHERE id = %s;""", 
                  (interesting_record_id,))

for foo, bar, baz, quux in cursor.fetchall():
    frobnicate(foo + bar, baz * quux)
```

The query formatting method is one of the DB-API standards, but happens to be the preferred method for Psycopg2; other DB-API adapters might suggest a different convention which will be fine.

Writing queries like this, where implicit tuple unpacking is used to work with the result set, has typically been more effective for me than trying to worry about matching Python variable names to SQL column names (which I usually only use to drop prefixes, and then only if I'm working with a subset of the column names such that the prefixes don't help to clarify things anymore), and is *much* better than remembering numerical column IDs.

This style also helps you avoid `SELECT * FROM table...`, which is just a maintenance disaster for anything but the simplest tables and queries.

So, not exactly the answer you were asking for, but possibly enlightening nonetheless.

Comment: Actually, that's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry: should have checked more carefully. It doesn't quite work. With SQLite, foo ends up being something like (123,) while with MySQL it ends up being ('foo': 123)

Comment: Getting results like that makes me wonder if your MySQL module is DB-API 2.0 compliant... if it's not, trying to substitute a different database module is going to be ugly. Which MySQL module are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQLdb... I don't know enough to know whether it's DB-API 2.0 compliant or not...

Comment: Somehow you're getting dictionaries out instead of the usual tuples. MySQLdb documentation suggests that you are using a DictCursor or one of its close relatives, instead of a plain cursor. Richard's advice on using row_factory is probably best if you want to get this behavior in a standard way.

Comment: Ah! I figured it out. The problem was that my cursor was a DictCursor. Now it works fine.

Comment: All these answers seem to rely on the connection remaining open to access by column name. However, I'd like to access them after the fact after closing the connection--is that possible? Right now I've added a dict for readability to access by index.

Answer (score 43):

In the five years since the question was asked and then answered, a very simple solution has arisen. Any new code can simply wrap the connection object with a row factory. Code example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('./someFile')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row        // Here's the magic!

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT name, age FROM someTable")
for row in cursor:
    print(row['name'])
```

Here are some [fine docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index). Enjoy!

Comment: The same answer was posted 2 years prior to this answer.

Answer (score 16):

To access columns by name, use the [`row_factory`](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/download/pysqlite/doc/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) attribute of the Connection instance.  It lets you set a function that takes the arguments `cursor` and `row`, and return whatever you'd like.  There's a few builtin to pysqlite, namely `sqlite3.Row`, which does what you've asked.

Comment: In the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index

Answer (score 16):

This can be done by adding a single line after the "connect" statment:

```
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

Check the documentation here:
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite API supports cursor.description so you can easily do it like this

```
headers = {}
for record in cursor.fetchall():
    if not headers:
        headers = dict((desc[0], idx) for idx,desc in cursor.description))
    data.append(record[headers['column_name']])
```

A little long winded but gets the job done.  I noticed they even have it in the factory.py file under dict_factory.

Answer (score 1):

kushal's answer to [this forum](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/755969) works fine:

> Use a DictCursor:

```
import MySQLdb.cursors

.
.
.
cursor = db.cursor (MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute (query)
rows = cursor.fetchall ()

for row in rows:
print row['employee_id']
```

Please take note that the column name is case sensitive.

Comment: Such a shame this answer is against the wrong question (sqlite rather than mysql) as it answered my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cursor description, like so:

```
rows = c.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for col_i, col in enumerate(row):   
        print("Attribute: {0:30} Value: {1}".format(c.description[col_i][0],col))
```