# How to display a SQL INNER JOIN HTML with Flask

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I've got some issues to display a value from another table (it would be easier to understand with code below) :

**contact.py**

```
def index():
    db = get_db()
    contacts = db.execute(
        'SELECT *'
        ' FROM contact INNER JOIN branche ON contact.branche_id = branche.branche_id'
        ' ORDER BY contact.nom ASC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('contact/index.html', contacts=contacts)
```

**templates/contact/index.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-light">
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Prénom</th>
          <th>Adresse Mail</th>
          <th>Code Postal</th>
          <th>Ville</th>
          <th>Téléphone Portable</th>
          <th>Branche</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
      <div runat="server" id="div_columns" >
        {% for contact in contacts %}
         <tr>
             <td>{{ contact['nom'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['prenom'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['telportable'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['adressemail'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['codepostal'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['ville'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ contact['telportable'] }}</td>
             <td>{{ branche['branche_nom'] }}</td>
             <td> 
                <a class="btn"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
                <a class="btn text-danger "><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
              <hr>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS branche;

CREATE TABLE contact (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  nom TEXT NOT NULL,
  prenom TEXT NOT NULL,
  adressemail TEXT NOT NULL,
  adressepostale TEXT NOT NULL,
  codepostal INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ville TEXT NOT NULL,
  telfixe INTEGER NOT NULL,
  telportable INTEGER NOT NULL,
  branche_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (branche_id) REFERENCES branche (branche_id)
);

CREATE TABLE branche (
  branche_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  branche_nom TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

All I want to do is to print *contact* informations (name, phone number, ...) and there is one information that isn't inside `contact` table, it's `branche_nom` inside the `branche` table, so where is my mistake? I don't have any error inside terminal computer or browser terminal

P.S : when I disable display of `branche_nom`, all lines stored inside DB are printed, I just have nothing I want to use another table

EDIT 1: Loading `branche` table

**contact.py**

```
def index():
    db = get_db()
    contacts = db.execute(
        'SELECT contact.nom, contact.prenom, contact.adressemail, contact.codepostal, contact.ville, contact.telportable, branche.branche_nom'
        ' FROM contact INNER JOIN branche ON contact.branche_id = branche.branche_id'
        ' ORDER BY contact.nom ASC'
    ).fetchall()
    branches = db.execute(
        'SELECT branche_nom'
        ' FROM branche INNER JOIN contact ON contact.branche_id = branche.branche_id'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('blog/index.html', contacts=contacts, branches=branches)
```

Screenshot of `Branche List` :

[image: branche list screenshot]

EDIT2 : **db.py**

```
import sqlite3  
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as d:
        db.executescript(d.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

Comment: You aren't passing a `branche` variable to your template at all, nor selecting any `branche` columns in the query.

Comment: @AKX i tried to add it, but nothing change (currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check branche table to be filled with relevant ID's, as inner join will return empty cursor when ID's on both table do not exist.

Second, I would try to avoid * in the select and go for either "SELECT contact.*,branche.*" or selecting actual columns of the tables.

Third, after trying you're code with sqlite, I have found that you should change in the html template your current iterator contact and not branche,

e.g.: not `<td>{{ branche['branche_nom'] }}</td>`
but `<td>{{ contact['branche_nom'] }}</td>`

Beside the typo, you have to add a command that will recognize your columns by names, immediately after connection init: `db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`

I have run your full example and it works!!
Full code:

```
%%writefile contact.py
from flask import Flask, escape, url_for
from flask import render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_db():
    db = sqlite3.connect(r"/home/david/sqlite/db/pythonsqlite.db")
    return db

@app.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    contacts = db.execute(
        'SELECT contact.nom, contact.prenom, contact.adressemail, contact.codepostal, contact.ville, contact.telportable, branche.branche_nom'
        ' FROM contact INNER JOIN branche ON contact.branche_id = branche.branche_id'
        ' ORDER BY contact.nom ASC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', contacts=contacts)
```

Results:

[image]

Main reason for the confusion, is how Jinja interprets the cursor and its variables(columns), different db has different DB-API, your first approach luckily "understands" the names columns (but not all from the branche table), as if you try to iterate over contacts you will be able to access only the indexed column (by numbers), with the added feature of sqlite3.Row the cursor will allow you to access column by name, and that is what eventually you're passing to the template.
got this explanations from: [How can I reference columns by their names in python calling SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576933/how-can-i-reference-columns-by-their-names-in-python-calling-sqlite)

Comment: 1. which db you're using, it can help checking syntax? did you succeed runing the query directly against db?
2. you have ambiguous column (branche_id) that can cause headache if not handled correctly, if you can, just for the sake of test, I would rename it different in each table, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I'm using SQLite as db, and which query did you speak about? without any link to `branche` table, everything works well, it's when I want to include a reference in order to display the `branche` name next to others `contact` information

Comment: I think I have found you're typo error, in the template you should replace  branche['branche_nom'] with  contact['branche_nom'], since you're itrating over contacts that already has the column branche_nom but you are using contact for each line, not branche.

Comment: thanks to your explanation, I've understand where is the issue, but I don't know how to resolve it; I've add **db.py** file which contains db loading, and also in the *html* file, the loop `for contact in contacts` didn't work at all, `contacts` is be like =NULL, what is the issue with my `db.execute` function? Or coud it be a problem with another function?

Comment: most important code is **db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row** , since it wraps the fetched cursor with columns name you can use. just for testing try to read cursor and iterate over the columns, without this line of code you'll be able to access only by index number, and with this code you can access it by name.